# Динамическое изменение элементов сайта

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, веб-сайт

Есть небольшая проблема. На сайте задана динамическая высота для сайдбара и контента. Соответственно как только в контенте или сайдбаре появляется содержимое они увеличиваются. Если в сайдбаре больше наполнения, чем в контенте он становится по высоте больше контента. Вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы при увеличение содержимого в одном элементе, в другом появлялось бы пустое место и соответственно один элемент становился равен другому.(Без фиксированных размеров, конечно же)

код

```
<div class="incontent">
<content>
</content>
 </div>
<?php require "blocks/aside.php"?>
 </div>
    
content{
width:70%;
background-color:lightgray;
float:left;
min-height: 1500px;

}

aside{
background-color: gray;
width:30%;
float:left;
min-height: 1500px;
}
```

Comment: Для начала приложите ваш код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, вы можете завернуть оба блока в родительский `flex`-контейнер. С помощью `align-items: stretch` мы заставляем родительский блок растягивать блоки-потомки по всей длине [дополнительной оси](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#flexbox_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8).

Таким образом, когда высота одного из блоков-потомков увеличивается, также увеличивается высота родительского блока, и вместе с этим высота всех его потомков:

```css
#wrapper {
   display: flex;
   align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  background-color: cyan;
}

#content {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
  <div id="content">
    Content...
    <br />
    more content...
  </div>
</div>
```